# Find the element representing evaluation at a point in the Hilbert space of $L^2$ holomorphic functions on the disk

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

The space $S$ of holomorphic functions on the disk $\mathbb{D}$ which are also in $L^2(\mathbb{D})$ is a Hilbert space, with the inner product being $\langle f, g\rangle = \int f(z) \overline{g(z)} dA(z)$, where $dA$ denotes Lebesgue measure. The linear functional $L_{z_0}$, given by $f\mapsto f(z_0)$, is a bounded linear functional on $S$, and thus there must exist some $g_{z_0}\in S$ so that $L_{z_0}(f) = \langle f, g_{z_0}\rangle$ for all $f$. It turns out, this function is given by 
$$g_{z_0}(w) = \frac{1}{(1-\overline{z_0}z)^2}$$
I have seen this proven by representing $f$ and $g$ as power series, performing the multiplication, and working out the coefficients of the $g$ power series by brute force, which is fine. But I want to think that there is an easier way to do it, or at least a more conceptually satisfying way. For example, I would think to do it by first noting that for $z_0 = 0$, $g_{z_0}$ can be a constant function (I believe $1/\pi$), and then getting the general case by composing with a Mobius transformation; indeed, the function $g_{z_0}$ is closely related to the derivative of such a Mobius transformation, but I have not been able to get such an approach to work. I realized that I don't really know any machinery for working with non-holomorphic functions (like $\overline{g_{z_0}}$), and area integrals of complex functions are also somewhat new to me.

In sum, **Can anyone give me a conceptually satisfying way of approaching this problem, hopefully one that uses some classical complex analysis tricks like Cauchy's integral formula, Mobius transformations, and the like?**

Or, **Can you direct me to a resource which has the basic tools for solving this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Möbius transformation idea is good, but it needs one extra thing  to work. We know that 
$$
f(0) = \frac{1}{\pi}\iint_{|z|<1} f(z)\,dA(z)
\tag1$$
Given $z_0$, apply (1)  to $g = (f\circ \phi^{-1})(\phi^{-1})'$ where $\phi(z)=  (z-z_0)/(1-\bar z_0z) $ is a Möbius transformation sending $z_0$ to $ 0$. (Here, $(\phi^{-1})'$ is that extra thing.) Since
$$\phi'(z) = \frac{1-\bar z_0 z + \bar z_0(z-z_0) }{(1-\bar z_0 z)^2} = \frac{1- |z_0|^2 }{(1-\bar z_0 z)^2} \tag2$$
the change of variables $z=\phi(w)$ yields
$$
 f(z_0) (\phi^{-1})'(0) = g(0) =  \frac{1}{\pi}\iint_{|z|<1} g(z)\,dA(z)
=  \frac{1}{\pi}\iint_{|w|<1} \frac{f(w)}{\phi'(w)} |\phi'(w)|^2\,dA(w)
\tag3$$
This simplifies to 
$$
 \frac{f(z_0)}{\phi'(z_0)} = \frac{1}{\pi}\iint_{|w|<1}  f(w) \overline{\phi'(w)}  \,dA(w)
\tag4$$
and, using (2), further simplifies to 
$$
 f(z_0) (1-|z_0|^2)  = \frac{1}{\pi}\iint_{|w|<1}  f(w) \frac{1-|z_0|^2}{(1-z_0 \bar w)^2}  \,dA(w)
\tag6$$
which is the desired result
$$
 f(z_0)   = \frac{1}{\pi}\iint_{|w|<1}  f(w) \frac{1}{(1-z_0 \bar w)^2}  \,dA(w)
\tag7$$

What's the idea of putting the derivative factor $(\phi^{-1})'$ in the formula for $g$? Without it we'd end up with the Jacobian $|\phi'|^2 = \phi'\overline{\phi'}$ as the factor of $f$ on the right hand side of (3). And we want an antiholomorphic weight there, so $\phi'$ has to be canceled off.

Comment: This is beautiful, thank you. That’s exactly what I needed.